# Can't install postgres due to texlive error

Tags: apt, postgresql, texlive

I try to apt-get install postgresql but it fails with dependency complaints about texlive.

The error message suggests apt --fix-broken install but that also fails with complaints about texlive.

I do use texlive but I'm not sure what, if anything, it has to do with postgres.

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

`cat /etc/lsb-release`:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux TroysYoga 4.4.0-174-generic #204-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 29 06:41:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Console output:

```
troy@TroysYoga:~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql
[sudo] password for troy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 context : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2017)
           Depends: texlive-base (>= 2017) but 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
           Depends: texlive-metapost (>= 2017) but 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-freefont but it is not installable
 dvipng : Depends: texlive-base-bin
 feynmf : Depends: texlive-font-utils but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
 fragmaster : Depends: texlive-base-bin
              Depends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: texlive-font-utils but it is not going to be installed
 imagemagick-6.q16 : Depends: libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2) but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra
 latex-cjk-common : Depends: texlive-font-utils (>= 2007.dfsg.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
 obex-data-server : Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2) but it is not installable
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-10 but it is not going to be installed
 prosper : Depends: texlive-latex-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but 2015.20160320-1 is to be installed
 tex4ht-common : Depends: texlive-base-bin
                 Recommends: tex4ht
 texlive : Depends: texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2017.20170628) but 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
           Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2017.20170628) but 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
           Depends: texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2017.20170628) but 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 texlive-base : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2017.20170628) but 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 texlive-formats-extra : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-games : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-htmlxml : Depends: texlive-formats-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but 2015.20160320-1 is to be installed
                   Depends: texlive-latex-extra (>= 2017.20170628) but 2015.20160320-1 is to be installed
                   Depends: texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2017.20170628) but 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                   Depends: texlive-plain-generic (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
 texlive-humanities : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-lang-cjk : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-lang-cyrillic : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-lang-czechslovak : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-lang-greek : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-lang-indic : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-lang-japanese : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-lang-korean : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-lang-polish : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-latex-base : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-latex-extra : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-latex-recommended : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-luatex : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-math-extra : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-metapost : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-music : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-omega : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-pictures : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-pstricks : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
                    Recommends: texlive-font-utils but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
 texlive-science : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 texlive-xetex : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2015.20160222.37495-1)
 tipa : Depends: texlive-base-bin
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

troy@TroysYoga:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
[sudo] password for troy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  appstream caribou context context-modules dleyna-server
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts fonts-arphic-bkai00mp
  fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp fonts-arphic-gkai00mp
  fonts-baekmuk fonts-cabin fonts-comfortaa fonts-ebgaramond
  fonts-ebgaramond-extra fonts-font-awesome fonts-freefont-otf
  fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-baskerville fonts-gfs-bodoni-classic
  fonts-gfs-complutum fonts-gfs-didot fonts-gfs-didot-classic fonts-gfs-gazis
  fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga fonts-gfs-porson fonts-gfs-solomos
  fonts-gfs-theokritos fonts-hosny-amiri fonts-junicode fonts-lobster
  fonts-lobstertwo fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-roboto-hinted
  fonts-sil-gentiumplus fonts-unfonts-core fonts-unfonts-extra gcc-5-base:i386
  gcc-6-base:i386 gir1.2-caribou-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0
  gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0
  gnome-backgrounds gnome-software-common imagemagick-common latex-cjk-all
  latex-cjk-chinese latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp
  latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp
  latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp latex-cjk-common latex-cjk-japanese
  latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab latex-cjk-korean latex-cjk-thai lcdf-typetools
  libappstream3 libboost-date-time1.58.0 libcapnp-0.5.3 libcaribou-common
  libcaribou0 libchromaprint0 libdata-alias-perl
  libdleyna-connector-dbus-1.0-1 libdleyna-core-1.0-3 libdns-export162
  libfcitx-gclient0 libfwupd1 libgrilo-0.2-1 libgtkspell3-3-0
  libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libgweather-3-6 libhal-storage1
  libhal1 libhud2 libical1a libicu4j-java libidn11:i386 libieee1284-3:i386
  libisc-export160 libjetty8-java libjson-c2:i386 libmozjs-24-0v5
  libnma-common libopencv-calib3d2.4v5 libopencv-contrib2.4v5
  libopencv-features2d2.4v5 libopencv-flann2.4v5 libopencv-legacy2.4v5
  libopencv-ml2.4v5 liborcus-0.10-0v5 libparams-validate-perl libpodofo0.9.3
  libprocps4 libprotobuf-lite9v5 libqcustomplot1.3 libqt5clucene5
  libqt5feedback5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5organizer5 libreoffice-gtk
  libreoffice-gtk2 librhythmbox-core9 libruby2.3 libservlet3.0-java
  libsodium18 libsrtp0 libtomcat7-java libtracker-sparql-1.0-0
  libunity-action-qt1 libvpx3:i386 libwebpdemux1 libwebrtc-audio-processing-0
  libxapian-1.3-5 onboard-data plainbox-provider-checkbox
  plainbox-provider-resource-generic prosper python3-pyasn1 python3.5
  python3.5-minimal qml-module-qtfeedback qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects
  qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-window2
  qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin
  rename ruby2.3 suru-icon-theme texlive-fonts-extra-doc texlive-games
  texlive-generic-extra texlive-htmlxml texlive-humanities
  texlive-humanities-doc texlive-lang-african texlive-lang-arabic
  texlive-lang-chinese texlive-lang-cjk texlive-lang-cyrillic
  texlive-lang-czechslovak texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-european
  texlive-lang-french texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-greek
  texlive-lang-indic texlive-lang-italian texlive-lang-japanese
  texlive-lang-korean texlive-lang-other texlive-lang-polish
  texlive-lang-portuguese texlive-lang-spanish texlive-omega
  texlive-plain-extra texlive-science ubuntu-mobile-icons
  ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-arphic-bkai00mp fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp
  fonts-arphic-gkai00mp fonts-baekmuk fonts-unfonts-core fonts-unfonts-extra
  imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16 libkpathsea6 libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra
  libmime-charset-perl libostyle1c2 libptexenc1 libsombok3 libsynctex1
  libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 libunicode-linebreak-perl obex-data-server
  openjade prerex texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils
  texlive-font-utils texlive-fonts-extra-doc texlive-fonts-recommended
  texlive-formats-extra texlive-games texlive-generic-extra
  texlive-generic-recommended texlive-humanities texlive-humanities-doc
  texlive-lang-african texlive-lang-arabic texlive-lang-chinese
  texlive-lang-cjk texlive-lang-cyrillic texlive-lang-czechslovak
  texlive-lang-english texlive-lang-european texlive-lang-french
  texlive-lang-german texlive-lang-greek texlive-lang-indic
  texlive-lang-italian texlive-lang-japanese texlive-lang-korean
  texlive-lang-other texlive-lang-polish texlive-lang-portuguese
  texlive-lang-spanish texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc
  texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-latex-recommended
  texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex texlive-metapost
  texlive-metapost-doc texlive-music texlive-omega texlive-pictures
  texlive-pictures-doc texlive-plain-extra texlive-plain-generic
  texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc texlive-publishers
  texlive-publishers-doc texlive-science texlive-science-doc texlive-xetex
Suggested packages:
  imagemagick-doc autotrace curl enscript gimp grads graphviz hp2xx html2ps
  mplayer povray radiance ufraw-batch libjxr-tools libencode-hanextra-perl
  libpod2-base-perl perl-tk texlive-fonts-extra icc-profiles
  libspreadsheet-parseexcel-perl dot2tex ruby-tcltk | libtcltk-ruby
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  tex4ht-common texlive-math-extra
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-arphic-bkai00mp fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp
  fonts-arphic-gkai00mp fonts-baekmuk fonts-unfonts-core fonts-unfonts-extra
  libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra libmime-charset-perl libostyle1c2 libsombok3
  libunicode-linebreak-perl openjade texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils
  texlive-font-utils texlive-plain-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16 libkpathsea6 libptexenc1 libsynctex1
  libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 obex-data-server prerex texlive-base
  texlive-fonts-extra-doc texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-formats-extra
  texlive-games texlive-generic-extra texlive-generic-recommended
  texlive-humanities texlive-humanities-doc texlive-lang-african
  texlive-lang-arabic texlive-lang-chinese texlive-lang-cjk
  texlive-lang-cyrillic texlive-lang-czechslovak texlive-lang-english
  texlive-lang-european texlive-lang-french texlive-lang-german
  texlive-lang-greek texlive-lang-indic texlive-lang-italian
  texlive-lang-japanese texlive-lang-korean texlive-lang-other
  texlive-lang-polish texlive-lang-portuguese texlive-lang-spanish
  texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-latex-extra
  texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-latex-recommended
  texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-luatex texlive-metapost
  texlive-metapost-doc texlive-music texlive-omega texlive-pictures
  texlive-pictures-doc texlive-plain-extra texlive-pstricks
  texlive-pstricks-doc texlive-publishers texlive-publishers-doc
  texlive-science texlive-science-doc texlive-xetex
58 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 2 to remove and 308 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,805 MB of archives.
After this operation, 616 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 578014 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2017.20180305-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-fonts-extra-doc (2017.20180305-2) over (2015.20160320-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2017.20180305-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/mweights/README', which is also in package texlive-latex-extra-doc 2015.20160320-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2017.20180305-2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: We don't know your release, thus cannot do much (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=texlive) so can't see which problem applies to you.  I would say from https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=texlive-base&searchon=names that your sources aren't pure & are your problem (ie. *polluted*), but I'm guessing due to insufficient detail provided.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `postgresql`. You left the installation in a bit of mess after you tried to install texlive, and now the `apt` function won't install anything until that has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Here's some context.  I just upgraded to 18.04 yesterday (from 16.04, which was out-of-date).  I installed texlive years ago, but was still able to use apt after that.  What can I do to clean things up and get apt working again?

Comment: Show us `cut /etc/apt/sources.list`, `cut /etc/lsb-release`, `uname -a` but remove all commented records from sources.list before posting it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

- Your `sources.list` should look like:

  ```
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
  ```
- Temporarily move all your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` repositories to some safe place
- Remove all packages with conflicting dependencies. But make sure there's no important system packages. You could remove `texlive` and then use autoremove: `sudo apt purge texlive && sudo apt autoremove` to do it faster
- `sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
- Try to install `postgresql` again

Comment: Gryru, thanks.  Will try and post about the results.  I suspect I might have to remove a bunch of texlive packages individually, which is fine, but a nuisance.  Wish me luck!

Comment: Yes, it could be a long journey. Good luck)

Comment: I fixed the problem by removing the hundred or so texlive packages from the error logs and their dependencies.  It was a pain, and I will have to reinstall texlive, but at least now apt works again, and I was able to install Postgres!  sudo apt purge texlive did not work, which is why I had to resort to sudo dpkg -P and purging the packages one-by-one.  Not sure if backing up the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* repos was necessary, but I did that, too.